# How to save the position of my div when the page is load without dragging the div?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, position

Hi I am currently saving the div using follow method

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   $( ".ex" ).draggable({containment:'parent',cursor:'pointer',opacity:0.6,



     stop : function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
               var x = $(this).position().left;
               var y = $(this).position().top;

                 $.ajax({
        url: "changeContact.php", /* You need to enter the URL of your server side script*/
        type: "POST",
          /* add the other variables here or serialize the entire form. 
          Image data must be URI encoded */
        data:{
                cid:id,
                x: x,
                y: y
                },  
        success: function(msg)
        {

        }

            })
           } 
});

});
```

PHP

```
$qry = "SELECT * from contact Where CustomerID='$pid'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo '<div class="ex" id="'.$row["ContactID"].'">';
echo '</div>';

}
```

How to save the position of each data separately when the page is onload?Is there any way it will call the Ajax method by itself without drag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend putting the code that performs the AJAX call into its own function. This way, you can call it once when the page is loaded and also from inside the draggable code:

```
$(function ($) { // $(function () ... is the same as $(document).ready(function () ... - just quicker

    function doAjax (data) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'changeContact.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                // ...
            }
        });
    }

    function onDraggableStop (event, ui) {
        doAjax({
            cid: this.id,
            x: ui.offset.left,
            y: ui.offset.top
        });
    }

    function onPageLoad () {
        var position = $(this).position();

        doAjax({
            cid: this.id,
            x: position.left,
            y: position.top
        });
    }

    $( ".ex" )
        .each(onPageLoad) // for all found elements: fire the ajax call immediately

        // set up dragging support
        .draggable({
            containment: 'parent',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            opacity: 0.6,
            stop : onDraggableStop // fire the ajax call for the element that just stopped dragging
        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Oh and for the issue with the missing IDs... I guess the HTML for those elements is generated dynamically on the server? Just set their appropriate IDs there - no need to fuzz around on the client so much. If those entries are coming from a database, use their unique id (probably with a prefix) as html node ID.

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing the actual HTML I can only take wild guesses here ;) jQuery UI's "draggable" moves the element that's dragged around by simply putting `position: absolute;` on it and changing the `top` and `left` as needed. The -5 you're getting, though...

It might be one of the ancestor elements is positioned `relative` and thus serves as the offset parent.

But as I said - that's all just guessing and speculating here ;)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

1. User loads the page 
2. Page is generated on the server with any number of `div`s:

    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="ex" id="123"></div>
    <div class="ex" id="234"></div>
    <div class="ex" id="345"></div>
    <!-- ... -->

3. For each of those `div`s there's an AJAX call that sends the information `id, x, y` to the server. (does this produce the correct values?)
4. Every time you stop dragging one of these `div`s, there shall be another AJAX call - but these calls have buggy position info, **right**?

Comment: I guess you want to look at the 'offset' (which returns the absolute position of the dragged element inside its offsetParent) instead of 'position' (which gives you the delta between end position and start position for the dragged distance.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATED]**
Put additional `$.ajax()` request after `$(document).ready(function() {`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // additional ajaxrequest after pageload:

var obj = {windows:{}};

$(".ex").each(function() {

    obj.windows[$(this).attr('id') + 'posLeft'] = $(this).position().left;
    obj.windows[$(this).attr('id') + 'posTop'] = $(this).position().top;

})

$.ajax({
        url : 'server.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : obj,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data)
        {

        },
        error : function()
        {

        }
    });

   $( ".ex" ).draggable({
   //[...]
```

The additional $.ajax() will be executed after pageload.

Your php-script is able to get the data by `$_POST['windows']` for example. You can use an foreach-loop on that.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VQa3S/

Here are the data, will be sent to server in my fiddle:

[image: posted data]

In addition, be careful of your sql-query. It could be vulnerable by sql-injections. Use PDO and bind parameters.

Comment: It is not work currently my javascript is var id = $(this).attr("id");
               var x = $(this).position().left;
      var y = $(this).position().top;

Comment: I won't know my DIV ID, and I only got its class ID

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my code by an example.

Comment: I manage to get the position at -5, why is this so? my DIV position is set to relative, but when I save it, all the DIV stack on top on one another